# Routes issue in Express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, routes

Noob - trying to set up CRUD using routes on Express4 and Node. I've got the following GET and POST routes working ok, but DELETE and PUT are giving 404, Not Found errors, which is strange.

I'm using Postman for Chrome and have set the Content Type to application/json, and this is working ok - i do notice that on the DELETE and PUT queries the header still notes that it's sending as text/html, rather than JSON, although I've set both the RAW settings to JSON, and the Headers content type manually to application/json.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Todo = require('../models/Todo.js');

/* GET /todos listing. THIS IS WORKING*/
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(todos);
  });
});

/* POST /todos listings THIS IS WORKING*/
  router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
Todo.create(req.body, function(err, post){
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
    });
});

/* GET /todos/id THIS IS WORKING*/
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Todo.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* DELETE /todos/:id  NOT WORKING*/
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
  Todo.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Also this is a routes.js script that is being imported into app.js (see below):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var todos = require('./routes/todos');

// set our port
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 


//Requires the mongoose connection 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todoApp', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('connection error', err);
    } else {
        console.log('connection successful');
    }
});

var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/todos', todos);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});


// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});



// start app ===============================================
// startup our app at http://localhost:3080
app.listen(port);               

// shoutout to the user                     
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: please post your app.js so you can get help

Comment: app.js posted above - any help appreciated - thanks

Comment: can you post the image from POSTMan or the tool you may use to do the DELETE?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your implementation, it looks fine. Just one chance where i feel it can go wrong is, if we look into the documentation of [Model.findOneAndRemove(conditions, [options], [callback])](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove), you are going wrong in `[options]`.

In [options] we can do  :

- **sort**: if multiple docs are found by the conditions, sets the sort
  order to choose which doc to update
- **select**: sets the document fields to return

Try this, i hope it will solve your problem.
You mentioned that, PUT is also having same 404 issue, could you please update your post by including same. Let's understand where it is going wrong.

Comment: thanks for this - but the request isn't even being logged from within router.put(..) - before it runs through the Model.findOneAndRemove()

Comment: May i know how you are calling it from your view page?

Comment: views are called using jade

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you might want to check.

Your POST is working as intended, but your DELETEs and your PUTs aren't.  You've set the content type to application/json.

Given that you are using Express 4, and had to include a body parser yourself, do you happen to include the following lines?

```
var app = express();
// you probably have this, for application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

// extrapolating here, you only mentioned you were receiving 404s.
// you might be missing the following line?
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

In your delete route, you log the response object, is this a typo?  A more useful log would be of the request object - so you can determine what exactly the route thinks you sent.

Shot in the dark, but in the absence of additional information, I hope at least one of the answers are correct.

Comment: hey man - thanks for this - i have bodyParser.json included - the log is an artifact, from debugging - but console.log(req) would not output anything to the console, which suggests that the request isnt even running through the route.

Comment: @Mobaz in your delete you have console.log(**res**) i.e response instead of request as per your comment.

Comment: Mreh, without more information to go on, this is pretty hard to debug.  Can you write out at least the first line for all the methods (GET/POST/DELETE, etc.) you've declared for this resource?

Comment: I hate to ask these questions, but are you calling something like:
DELETE http://localhost:1337/todos/3
emphasis on delete and the id 3, and is it what postman is actually sending? (Sorry if you already did that)

Comment: Irysius - that was the answer I was being stupid and not adding the id i needed to PUT to in the URI string - which meant the server had no idea what to do - its been a pain, but I've learnt tons about node express routing and REST! - thanks for your contribution

Comment: Glad I can help.  Wouldn't mind being marked as having the correct answer. =)